# In .NET MAUI can you pass data transfer objects as query string parameters from one View to another?

Tags: c#, maui, query-string

I have worked through the .NET MAUI "Create a .NET MAUI App" startup tutorial.
I modified the tutorial a bit to use a sqlite database instead of files for each row in the CollectionView.
When they go to edit a row in the collection view they pass the id of the DTO of the row to a new view:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NotePage)}?{nameof(NotePage.ItemId)}={SelectedNote.ID}");
```

and the new view loads the ItemID with the following annotation:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
```

I was then taking that ItemId and doing another call to the database to return the DTO but since I am loading my data from the database I already have my DTO from the CollectionView and I just want to pass the whole thing over to the new view as some sort of query parameter to save resources.
How do I do this?

I saw someone online with a tutorial that showed to pass it like this:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NotePage), SelectedNote);
```

But Visual Studio says that my second parameter has to be a bool so I'm guessing that guys tutorial is wrong.

Anyone know if its possible to pass a DTO from a view in this way or something similar?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#pass-data) demonstrate how to do this

> Object-based navigation data can be passed with a GoToAsync overload
> that specifies an IDictionary<string, object> argument:

```
Animal animal = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Animal;
var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Bear", animal }
};
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"beardetails", navigationParameter);
```

then the receiving page or VM can do this

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Bear), "Bear")]
public partial class BearDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    Animal bear;
    public Animal Bear
    {
        get => bear;
        set
        {
            bear = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public BearDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```